# I made a MergeSort method with the firstHalf and secondHalf Method; index 0 ~ middle, middle+1 ~ end. However, this calls the StackOverFlow Error

Tags: java, mergesort

```java
public static void mergeSort(int[] data) {
    int[] left = firstHalf(data);
    int[] right = secondHalf(data);

    if (data.length > 1) {
        mergeSort(left);
        mergeSort(right);

        merge(data, left, right);  
    } 
}

public static void merge(int[] data, int[] left, int[] right) {    
    int tempArraySize = data.length;
    int mergedNumbers[] = new int[tempArraySize]; //Temp array to take the sorted array
    int mergePos;
    int leftPos;
    int rightPos;

    int middle = data.length / 2;

    mergePos = 0;
    leftPos = 0;     // 0 index                
    rightPos = middle + 1; //j is middle index

    while (leftPos <= middle && rightPos <= data.length - 1) {
        if (left[leftPos] < right[rightPos]) {
            mergedNumbers[mergePos] = left[leftPos];
            leftPos++;
        } else {
            mergedNumbers[mergePos] = right[rightPos];
            rightPos++;
        }
        mergePos++;
    }

    // when the right half array finishes sorting
    while (leftPos <= middle) {
        mergedNumbers[mergePos] = left[leftPos];
        leftPos++;
        mergePos++;
    }

    // when the left half array finishes sorting
    while (rightPos <= data.length - 1) {
        mergedNumbers[mergePos] = right[rightPos];
        rightPos++;
        mergePos++;
    }

    // give value to the original array
    for (mergePos = 0; mergePos < tempArraySize; ++mergePos) {
        data[leftPos + mergePos] = mergedNumbers[mergePos];
    }
}

public static int[] firstHalf(int[] data) {
    int[] tempFirst = new int[(data.length / 2) + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i <= data.length / 2; i++) {
        tempFirst[i] = data[i];
    }
    return tempFirst;
}

public static int[] secondHalf(int[] data) {
    int[] tempSecond = new int[(data.length / 2) + 1];

    for (int i = (data.length / 2) + 1; i < data.length; i++) { // Middle to the end
        for (int j = 0; j <= data.length / 2; j++) {
            tempSecond[j] = data[i];
        }
    }
    return tempSecond;
}
```

This is what I made.
My `mergeSort` method makes an error `java.lang.StackOverflowError`
What mistakes I made?
I made the `firstHalf` and `secondHalf` methods to get the index `0` ~ `middle` and `middle+1` ~ `end`.
Those methods are made to get the value from the original 'data' Array.
The `merge` method is as same as the common `MergeSort` code.
Do I have to build a base case in the `mergeSort` method?

Comment: can you please accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 2):

With this approach, it is simpler to return merged arrays. It would be faster to do a one time allocation of a temporary array, and use indexing to merge data between the two arrays rather than creating temporary arrays and copy data. Fixes noted in comments.

```
    public static int[] mergeSort(int[] data) {         // fix
        int[] left = firstHalf(data);
        int[] right = secondHalf(data);
        if(data.length < 2)                             // change
            return data;                                // fix
         left = mergeSort(left);                        // fix
         right = mergeSort(right);                      // fix
         return merge(left, right);                     // fix
    }

    public static int[] merge(int[] left, int[] right) {    // fix
        int mergedNumbers [] = new int[left.length+right.length];   // fix
        int mergePos = 0;                               // fix
        int leftPos = 0;                                // fix
        int rightPos = 0;                               // fix

        while (leftPos < left.length && rightPos < right.length) {  // fix
            if (left[leftPos] < right[rightPos]) {
                mergedNumbers[mergePos] = left[leftPos];
                leftPos++;
            } else {
                mergedNumbers[mergePos] = right[rightPos];
                rightPos++;
            }
            mergePos++;
        }
        while (leftPos < left.length) {                 // fix
              mergedNumbers[mergePos] = left[leftPos];
              leftPos++;
              mergePos++;
        }
        while (rightPos < right.length) {               // fix
              mergedNumbers[mergePos] = right[rightPos];
              rightPos++;
              mergePos++;
        }
        return mergedNumbers;                           // fix
    }

    public static int[] firstHalf(int[] data) {
        int j = (data.length/2);                        // fix
        int[] tempFirst = new int[j];                   // fix      
        for(int i = 0; i < tempFirst.length; i++)       // fix
            tempFirst[i] = data[i];
        return tempFirst;
    }

    public static int[] secondHalf(int[] data) {
        int j = (data.length/2);                        // fix
        int[] tempSecond = new int[data.length-j];      // fix
        for(int i = 0; i < tempSecond.length; i++)      // fix
            tempSecond[i] = data[i+j];                  // fix
        return tempSecond;
    }
```

The wiki article has a somewhat optimized approach for top down merge sort:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Top-down_implementation

Comment: Merging in place or into a newly allocated array is a different thing. As a matter of fact, you return the original array for lengths 0 and 1, which is inconsistent. This problem is very common in the literature, but may cause subtle bugs in real applications.

Comment: @chqrlie - If data length is 0 or 1, the code is returning a reference to the original array. If the user is aware of this, it shouldn't be a problem. Also there's no check for a data being null. The idea in this case was to follow the OP's code. Normally I would do a one time allocation, and sort the data in the caller's array.

Comment: *If the user is aware of this, it shouldn't be a problem.* That's true but i'm afraid in reality, few users are aware of the problem... I would also allocate a temporary array once, if the array is above a small threshold and compute another threshold, using insertion sort for small chunks and an even number of phases to produce the final sorted array directly into the original array. More fine tuning might be worthwhile for cache optimisation, or if large portions of the array are likely to be already sorted.

Comment: @chqrlie - in this case the only user is me. This is not how I would implement a merge sort for a library. EIther timsort, or a hybrid insertion / bottom up merge sort (most libraries use some variation of a hybrid insertion / merge sort). For an even number of passes, I determine pass count for basic merge sort, if it's odd, I use insertion sort for 32 elements, if even 64, that results in an even number of merge passes.

Comment: For others reading this, chqrlie's point is about shallow versus lazy versus deep copy of an array. Normally a sort will sort the caller's array, not return a sorted copy of the array. The main exceptions are database sort oriented "queries" that do make sorted copies of a database (since the original database is should not be modified by a query).

Answer (score 0):

The problems in your code come from the confusing convention to specify ranges with included boundaries. You should instead consider the upper bound to be excluded: this would avoid the numerous `+1`/`-1` adjustments required for the included convention, some of which are inconsistent in your code:

- `leftHalf` creates an array with length `(data.length / 2) + 1`, including the element at offset `mid = data.length / 2`. This is what the `merge` method expects, but is not optimal as it would make unbalanced halves for even sized arrays, and more problematically would return a 2 element slice for a 2 element array, which causes an infinite recursion and explains the **Stack Overflow** exception you get.
- `rightHalf` also creates an array with length `(data.length / 2) + 1`, which is incorrect, the length should be `array with length`data.length - ((data.length / 2) + 1)`, which would be an empty array for a 2 element array.
- Furthermore, `rightHalf` uses two nested `for` loops to copy the values from the argument array, which is incorrect.
- your index range into the `right` array is incorrect in the `merge` method.
- the index into `data` is incorrect in `data[leftPos + mergePos] = mergedNumbers[mergePos];` it should be just:

  ```
  data[mergePos] = mergedNumbers[mergePos];
  ```

Here is a modified version, with a less error prone convention:

```java
// sort elements in data in place
public static void mergeSort(int[] data) {
    if (data.length > 1) {
        int[] left = firstHalf(data);
        int[] right = secondHalf(data);

        mergeSort(left);
        mergeSort(right);
        merge(data, left, right);  
    }
}

public static void merge(int[] data, int[] left, int[] right) {
    int leftLength = left.length;
    int rightLength = right.length;
    int length = leftLength + rightLength;
    int mergedNumbers[] = new int[length]; //Temp array to received the merged array
    int leftPos = 0;
    int rightPos = 0;
    int mergePos = 0;

    while (leftPos < leftLength && rightPos < rightLength) {
        if (left[leftPos] <= right[rightPos]) {
            mergedNumbers[mergePos] = left[leftPos];
            leftPos++;
            mergePos++;
        } else {
            mergedNumbers[mergePos] = right[rightPos];
            rightPos++;
            mergePos++;
        }
    }

    // copy the remaining entries in the left half
    while (leftPos < leftLength) {
        mergedNumbers[mergePos] = left[leftPos];
        leftPos++;
        mergePos++;
    }

    // copy the remaining entries in the right half
    while (rightPos < rightLength) {
        mergedNumbers[mergePos] = right[rightPos];
        rightPos++;
        mergePos++;
    }

    // copy the values back to the original array
    for (mergePos = 0; mergePos < length; mergePos++) {
        data[mergePos] = mergedNumbers[mergePos];
    }
}

public static int[] firstHalf(int[] data) {
    int leftLength = data.length / 2;
    int[] tempFirst = new int[leftLength];

    for (int i = 0; i < leftLength; i++) {
        tempFirst[i] = data[i];
    }
    return tempFirst;
}

public static int[] secondHalf(int[] data) {
    int leftLength = data.length / 2;
    int rightLength = data.length - leftLength;
    int[] tempSecond = new int[rightLength];

    for (int i = 0; i < rightLength; i++) {
        tempSecond[i] = data[LeftLength + i];
    }
    return tempSecond;
}
```